# can session be used to cache data in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, database, session, caching, laravel-5.3

I am working on a project in laravel 5.3 where I need to get a big data from my DB. so what I am doing right now is getting data though Query and then saving it in session so that no further DB query is needed for next time.

Is it bad practice somehow? Or any other better alternative like DB caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel way to cache a query is like:

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function() {
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```

If the item does not exist in the cache, the Closure passed to the remember method will be executed and its result will be placed in the cache.

> The cache configuration is located at `config/cache.php`. In this file you may specify which cache driver you would like used by default throughout your application. Laravel supports popular caching backends like Memcached and Redis out of the box.